# How to condition my select based on boolean parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameters, boolean

I'm creating a stored procedure that should return a list of users based on a boolean flag `@status` as follows:

- If `status` is not informed, the query must return all users
- If 'status' is passed as `true`, the query must return only users where the column `LastAccess` is `not null`.
- If `status` is passed as false, the query must return users which column `LastAccess` is `null`.

This column is of type `datetime`.

I'm ok dealing the first use case, with `@status is null` in the last line of the following code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE selectUsersByStatus (
    @userId int,
    @status bit     
    )

AS

SELECT * from users

WHERE users.id = @userId
and (@status is null or CASE @status WHEN 1 THEN (users.LastAccess is not null) ELSE (users.LastAccess is null))
```

However the rest of the line obviously doesn't work. How to proceed?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try simple:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE selectUsersByStatus (
    @userId int,
    @status bit     
    )

AS

SELECT * from users

WHERE users.id = @userId
and (@status is null OR (@status = 1 AND users.LastAccess IS NOT NULL) OR (@status = 0 AND users.LastAccess IS NULL))
```